# SQL Select - "If that user-group combination has an attribute of X, don't return any records with that user-group combination"

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to write a SQL statement for auditing purposes. Basically, the purpose of it can be summarized as "Return all user-group combinations where the user is not currently Approved for **ANY ROLES** in that group".

For example, take the following records:

```
ID  UserId  GroupId  Role       Status
----------------------------------------
1   1       10       User       Approved
2   1       10       Editor     Denied

3   1       15       User       Denied

4   2       20       User       Pending 
5   2       20       Editor     Denied  
6   2       20       Admin      Denied

7   2       25       User       Approved
```

As you can see, there are 4 basic User-Group combos here:

- User 1 applied to be a User and Editor in Group10 and was denied as Editor, but Approved as User. We do not want any of this user's records to be returned, as he was approved for a role.
- User 1 applied to be a User in Group15 and was Denied. This record should be returned as he has no membership in Group 15.
- User 2 applied to be a User, Editor, and Admin in Group20. He was denied for Editor and Admin, but is still pending User privileges. His record should be returned as he currently has no membership.
- User 2 applied to be a User in Group25 and he was Approved. His record shouldn't be returned - he is a member.

I've tried to do this via an INNER JOIN of the group on itself on UserId and GroupId, but that doesn't work as Records are created where ID 1 joins ID 1 and simple logic (return everything that doesn't have any Status=Approved) doesn't work because both statuses are the same.

I've got a feeling that a NOT could be useful, but I can't figure out a way to get all User-Group combos that have a value of Approved (so I can then Select NOT it).

The correct query should return records corresponding to ID 3, and ID 4-6 (any of 4/5/6, or all of them). Any guidance would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID  INT, UserId  INT, GroupId  INT, Role  VARCHAR(10), Status VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(1 ,  1,  10  ,'User','Approved'),
(2 ,  1,  10  ,'Editor','Denied'),
(3 ,  1,  15  ,'User','Denied'),
(4 ,  2,  20  ,'User','Pending'),
(5 ,  2,  20  ,'Editor','Denied'),
(6 ,  2,  20  ,'Admin','Denied'),
(7 ,  2,  25  ,'User','Approved')

SELECT * FROM @Table T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM @Table T2 
    WHERE T1.UserId = T2.UserID 
        and T1.GroupId = T2.GroupId
        AND T2.Status ='Approved')
```

Result:

```
ID          UserId      GroupId     Role       Status
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
3           1           15          User       Denied
4           2           20          User       Pending
5           2           20          Editor     Denied
6           2           20          Admin      Denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate your table by the `UserId` and `GroupId`, and return only those users who never have a single record with an approved status in a particular group:

```
SELECT UserId, GroupId
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY UserId, GroupId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

If you instead want to return all the users' matching records, then we can modify the above by adding a join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UserId, GroupId
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY UserId, GroupId
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) t2
    ON t1.UserId = t2.UserId AND
       t1.GroupId = t2.GroupId;
```